# link to nested comment 'show' action from articles controller 'show' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to link to the 'show' action of a nested Comment from the 'show' action of its parent Articles controller.

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

I understand the link should look like this:

```
<%= link_to "View Comment", article_comment_path(@article, @comment) %>
```

And @article is defined in the ArticlesController as:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = ???
end
```

I am confused how to define @comment in order to get the proper comment :id for the link to work.

The @comment also belongs_to the current_user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an article has more than one comment, you will want to retrieve the collection and loop over it.

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @article.comments
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= link_to "View Comment", article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
<% end %>
```

Better, you can just do it in the view:

```
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= link_to "View Comment", article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
<% end %>
```

Then you don't need to define `@comments` in the controller.